# Can I create a custom JUnit 5 annotation @Defect("Ticket-ID") and map that to @Tag("Ticket-ID")

Tags: annotations, junit5

I want to know how to add a parameter to an annotation, and then use that parameter to help compose an annotation.

As a simple example, suppose I want to define `@Defect(<Ticket-ID>)`.  Among other things, that annotation will add `@Tag(<Ticket-Id>)`.

Can I do this?  If so, what would the code look like?

Comment: I'm interested in this because I'd like to use an annotation to make test result reporting easier -- ex, adding a @TestId("5000") tag to a test to allow a post test run upload to a reporting tool. Being able to tie an ID to a test case in a way where I can access the id within my tests would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can't map @Defect() to @Tag(), don't see the point on it also. You would be only changing Tag name.
What you can do is, create an interface to map @Tag("Defect") and then add a value as a parameter to it:

```
@Target({TYPE, METHOD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Test
@Tag("Defect")
@interface Defect {
    int value();
}
```

Then you could use it like:

```
@Defect("JiraIssue-1234");
```

You can also get the value you pass as parameter like:

```
AnnotationSupport.findAnnotation(_extensionContext.getElement(), Defect.class).get().value()
```

Comment: The reason for the original ask was to make it easy to run all tests associated with a particular defect.  Putting a unique value in the @Tag() makes that easy.  If I put the ticket inside the Defect annotation, can I compose a command-line that runs all of the tests for that ticket?

Comment: Also, the point of the @Defect annotation was to enable special logic that changes validation behavior.  A test case that is broken will have special logic to validate that it is still broken in the same way.  If it is, the test case is marked as aborted.  Otherwise, it fails.  So the presence of the annotation does more than just serve as an alias for @Tag().